# Как менять состояние CheckBox по наличию текста в Edit?

Tags: delphi

Как сделать, чтобы если есть текст в `Edit1`, значит `CheckBox1` активный (то есть стоит галочка). Если `Edit1` пустой, то в `CheckBox1` галочка снята.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобралась, кому интересно то ответ:

```
CheckBox1.Checked :=Edit1.Text<>'';
```